# Full width UICollectionViewCells, autolayout constraints and rotating issues

Tags: swift, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to use autolayout for my UICollectionViewCells and need the width to always be the width of the collectionView.  Everything is working fine until I rotate the screen (I know you can just reload the data, but wondering if there's a more elegant solution)

Essentially I have the following

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var cellWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.frame = bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        guard let superview = superview else {
            return
        }

        cellWidthConstraint.constant = superview.frame.width
    }}
```

The cell setup

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    cell.cellWidthConstraint.constant = collectionView.frame.width

    return cell
}
```

And rotation detection

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    guard let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
        return
    }

    flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

And the `estimatedItemSize` has been set to `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`

This works, however there are layout constraints breaking when I rotate the device which are coming from the constraint set on the contentView.  I have no idea why they're occurring but if anyone could shed some light or has a better method of doing this that would be great!

**UPDATE**

After changing `viewWillTransition` to this...

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

I now get a

> The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.

when rotating from landscape to portrait, even though the layout is being invalidated

Answer (score 0):

You should use this delegate method to control/change the size of your cells:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cellHeight);
}
```

This will make your cell the size you return, without needing to break constraints, or reconfiguring constraints on screen rotation.

Comment: I am avoiding using this because I want my cells to be variable in height and worked out with autolayout